# rails how to render a file with correct filename

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is tough one to explain so i'll try my best, and hopefully edit the question if people need more information. I am not providing exact code, but merely an example of the issue.

I am using rails 2.3.8. I am on Unix.

I have a bunch of files under a directory not Apache accessible. (i.e. /data/files/file.rpk)

I have the following in my view.

```
link_to "RPK File", :controller => 'mycontroller', :action=> 'myaction', :file => '/data/files/file.rpk'
```

I have the following in my controller.

```
def myaction
  if FileTest.exists?(params[:file])
    render :file => params[:file]  
  end
end
```

When i select the link on the page i get a download prompt for my desired file, but the name of the file is "myaction" instead of the filename.

Thoughts on how i could get it named correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [send_file](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html#method-i-send_file). The x_sendfile option prevents that your workers keep busy while transferring the actual file. You can read more about that in [this blogpost](http://www.therailsway.com/2009/2/22/file-downloads-done-right).

```
send_file path_to_file_on_filesystem, :type => "application/zip", :x_sendfile => true
```

Comment: Ah, yes `send_file` is the more appropriate choice here. Nice catch.

Answer (score 8):

You want to use `send_data` with the `:filename` option. See the [API documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActionController/Streaming/send_data).

You want to be **extremely careful** with this, though. Never ever trust the client/user! They will send `file=../../../../etc/group` or something in order to read arbitrary files on your system, so be very sure to sanitize that value before passing it to any file-reading methods.

Comment: This was a helpful answer as well.